# TFS build error path incorrect

Tags: tfs

I have the following TFS structure:

FolderA --> FolderB --> FolderC

In the build definition the Solution is set to FolderB/FolderC/MySolution.sln
Under get sources the Workspace is mapped to $/FolderA

When I build I get an error because the path is missing FolderA.

C:\agent_work\2\s\FolderB\FolderC\MySolution.sln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

..\s is the root -level of your mapping (in this case $/FolderA = ..\s).
If you need the path to be ..\s\FolderA (why ?) go to your build -> "Get sources" -> "workspace mappings" and configure the field "Local path under $(build.sourcesdirectory)" with "FolderA"

Comment: The correct folder structure is C:\agent_work\2\s\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\MySolution.sln but it is missing from the path when compiling. The Local path is already set to FolderA

Comment: No sorry, I didn't change anything. It was already like you suggested and it doesn't work.

Comment: s is not FolderA FolderA is inside folder s, but when compiling FolderA is missing and the solution is not found.

Comment: path to your solution is configured correctly ? how is it configured ?

Comment: Do you mean in the build defintion solution field? It is set to FolderB/FolderC/MySolution.sln

Comment: Shouldn't it be "FolderA/ FolderB/FolderC/MySolution.sln" ?

Comment: If I add FolderA and build it doesn´t find the solution and gives me the error System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The directory is not empty

Comment: So " FolderB/FolderC/MySolution.sln" runs the get sources successfully but fails when trying to build the solution with the error MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. and below it you will see the path C:\agent_work\2\s\FolderB\FolderC\MySolution.sln

Comment: No wait, now it works with FolderA in the path :s strange